# class_loader poco error

Tags: ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to onstall hydro to my macbook air and i got the following error when i'm building the catkin workspace:

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package):
Found package configuration file:

```
/Users/.../ros_catkin_ws/src/class_loader/cmake/PocoConfig.cmake
```

but it set Poco_FOUND to FALSE so package "Poco" is considered to be NOT
FOUND.

I didn't find any solutions, maybe you have one..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/110511/class_loader-poco-error/) by [4ft4](https://answers.ros.org/users/9946/4ft4/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2013-12-15

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [that_guy318](https://answers.ros.org/users/20951/that_guy318/) on 2014-11-27**:
I'm having the same problem after both installing poco from the repositories (libpoco-dev) and by downloading and compiling the source.  No matter what I do with poco and the cmakelists file I can't get it to find poco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've managed to fix that particular error by just installing poco via homebrew

```
brew install poco
```

But now i'm stuck with another error a little bit further down the way

---

Originally posted by [devmexx](https://answers.ros.org/users/12641/devmexx/) with karma: 26 on 2014-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1